# How do you name a many-to-many relationship table using Fluent Api?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, many-to-many, ef-fluent-api, tablename

I have created a **many-to-many** relationship, and the name the table (the one that has the Id of both records / objects) has doesn't appeal to me.

So how can I name that table using **Fluent Api**? By a usual table I'd use `ToTable("Name")`, but how do I do the same thing on this atypical table?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you still use the `ToTable()` method in conjunction with the `UsingEntity()` fluent api:

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<Post>()
    .HasMany(p => p.Tags)
    .WithMany(p => p.Posts)
    .UsingEntity(j => j.ToTable("PostTags"));
```

Comment: It claims that there's no such thing as **UsingEntity**.

Comment: This example was taken straight from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#join-entity-type-configuration). Have a look and check your EF Core version.

Comment: Okay, I'll check it out.